# How to generate random number with js from range starting from 1?

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I've been using this code to generate a random number with js:

```
var max = 10;
Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max + 1 ) );
```

From what I understand that will generate a number from 0 to 10, but what if I want to generate a random number from 1 to 10? or from 5 to 10?

Comment: Your code will actually generate 11, every time.

Comment: Yes, my bad. The plus should be a *

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do from 0 to 9, then you add one to the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from `x` instead of 0, then:

1. Subtract `x` from `max`
2. Do everything else as normal
3. Add `x` to the result